# Python 'requests' module to download an excel file from a download link which pops up a dialogue box

Tags: python, http, download, python-requests

I'm a novice trying to download a file from a link using the requests module of python.
When clicked, the link opens a window to choose the file name and a directory.
Here is the code I tried:

```
url = "http://dart.fss.or.kr/pdf/download/excel.do?lang=ko&rcp_no=20160516003174&dcm_no=5146351"
response = requests.get(url)
with open("test.xls", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

While it makes test.xls file, it is empty, even though I could save an excel file from the link manually. How can I handle such a link that pops up a download window instead of giving a file directly? How can I check the HTTP messages(?) that were communicated when I clicked the link?

Comment: Is your `f.write(response.content)` indented within the `with open` code block?

Comment: @Trollsors Thanks to you, I corrected my mistake in the question.

Answer (score 1):

the request expect also cookies , headers and parameters like this  :

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'PDFJSESSIONID': 'sOESblx1pDvLATuxG1GzATU71604r1Q9a74W0hbmzocJBzaqy1tDlpcM2Hd1VVMT.ZG1fcGRmL2ZpbGVyM19wZGZfbXMx',
    'WMONID': 'mOKYA_fvs-9',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9',
}

params = (
    ('lang', 'ko'),
    ('rcp_no', '20160516003174'),
    ('dcm_no', '514635'),
)

response = requests.get('http://dart.fss.or.kr/pdf/download/excel.do', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, verify=False)

with open("test.xls", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Now you have the excel with complete data

TIP: You can access to the complete request since your console Google Chrome (example) and then check it in Network

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Giovani! I succeeded in downloading an excel file using what you taught me. After a few trials, I found that it still works with "response = requests.get('http://dart.fss.or.kr/pdf/download/excel.do', headers=headers, params=params)" (without cookies). Here, let alone the "params", why is "headers" important in the "requests.get"? Why do you use only part of my original url link, that is, up to "xxx/excel.do"? (Googling told me that url that ends with ".do" is relevant to "Java Servlet", which I don't know.)

Comment: In fact, the "header" with only the "User-Agent" element works fine.

Comment: Yes...even you can use this curl and convert to python......Just Type in Google ....curl to python